# Vertx 4.4.4 SchemaParser deprecation

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I am using vertx 4.4.4 and tried to use the following code snippet

```
SchemaParser parser = SchemaParser.createDraft7SchemaParser(
      SchemaRouter.create(vertx, new SchemaRouterOptions()));
```

I get a deprecation warning for `SchemaParser, SchemaRouter, SchemaRouterOptions`

I tried to read through the docs to find what is the suggested approach but could not find it.

I later use the `parser` in the following code

```
router.post("/demo")
      .handler(new BodyHandlerImpl())
      .handler(ValidationHandlerBuilder.create(parser)
        .body(Bodies.json(objectSchemaBuilder))
          .body(Bodies.formUrlEncoded(objectSchemaBuilder))
        .build())
      .handler(this::greet);
```

Answer (score 0):

`SchemaParser` is deprecated in favor of [`SchemaRepository`](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-json-schema/java/#_schemarepository).

First, create the repository:

```
SchemaRepository sr = SchemaRepository.create(new JsonSchemaOptions().setDraft(Draft.DRAFT7));
```

Then use it in the `ValidationHandlerBuilder`:

```
router.post("/demo")
  .handler(BodyHandler.create())
  .handler(ValidationHandlerBuilder.create(sr)
    .body(Bodies.json(objectSchemaBuilder))
    .body(Bodies.formUrlEncoded(objectSchemaBuilder))
    .build())
  .handler(this::greet);
```

Comment: `ValidationHandlerBuilder.create()` looks like it expects a `SchemaParser` instance, not a `SchemaRepository`. I'm keen on learning how to move on from the deprecated use of `SchemaParser`, but I can't find any documentation on the new approach to validation. Can you point me/us to any if it's available?

Comment: Same issue, the documentation is inadequate and hampers developer adoption